# Postgres Query to compare fields and fetch data accordingly

Tags: sql, postgresql

Need help to create query to compare the data and fetch relevant data from table:

**Input**

| Field1 | Field2 |
| --- | --- |
| abc_ID | ID |
| abc | abc |
| abc_id_test | test |
| abc_id_test | abc test |
| abc_id_test_scenario | scenario |
| abc_id_test_scenario | cde test |

**Output**

| Field1 | Field2 |
| --- | --- |
| abc_id_test_scenario | cde test |

If field 2 contains string that matches with field 1  then I need to filter those records.

Comment: I don't understand this: "If field 2 contains only 1 word and it matches with field 1 words then I need to filter it." Your result has one row only and there field2 has two "words" (even this is already an assumption, you didn't tell us what you mean by "word"). Why should the row with field2 = "abc test" not appear in the result? Please put much more effort in your question and explain in detail the logic that should be applied.

Comment: Apologies @JonasMetzler.Corrected it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `unnest` and `string_to_array` combined to expand a string to a set of rows. then check rows from `Field2` not match `Field1`

```
with cte as (
  select Field1, Field2, unnest(string_to_array(Field2, ' ')) as item
  from mytable
)
select field1, Field2
from cte
where Field1 not like concat('%',item,'%')
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/71k87BlT)